# Sharing heavy calculations result when using DRF serializer with many=True

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

There is a simple DRF serializer which:

```
class MySeriliazer(serializers.Serializer):
    some_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_some_field(self, obj):
         some_list = utils.do_some_heavy_calculations()
         return some_list[obj.some_field]
```

As you see I have a `some_field` field which value is calculated via some function.

When I get a single object it's a big of a problem, but when I use this serializer with `many=True` thus receiving multiple objects `do_some_heave_calculations` get called for each, which is very expensive.

Moreover sometimes there are few fields which use the same heavy function. like:

```
class MySeriliazer(serializers.Serializer):
    some_field1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    some_field2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_some_field1(self, obj):
         some_list = utils.do_some_heavy_calculations()
         return some_list[obj.some_field1]

    def get_some_field2(self, obj):
         some_list = utils.do_some_heavy_calculations()
         return some_list[obj.some_field2]
```

Function is called twice for each object. Not good. What are the options to solve this? Sure enough I can grab these results from some cache which is updated every second. But I think it's possible to extract these calculations somehow and share them during the serialization process.

If needed - I use DRF generic views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform the call to `utils.do_some_heavy_calculations()` in the view before calling the serializer and pass it to the context (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context).

Then you can access it through `self.context`

Edit: Note that you can override the view's `get_serializer_context` to include your extra computation easily.